# Package Organization-Wide Addresses - Salesforce

Tags: salesforce

Is there a way to package Organization-Wide Addresses in Salesforce? I don't believe I see any related selection in the drop-down list when I look to package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. The [Metadata Coverage Report](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/metadata-coverage/51) is the source of truth for packageability; it shows that the `OrgWideEmailAddress` entity is not supported in any type of packaging or in Change Sets.